# How delete a property by groupId in product table?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want delete a specific property by groupId in product table. I try this example, but it does not work :

```php
$this->productRepository->delete([
   [
     'productId' => $productId,
     'properties' => [
         [
           'groupId' => $propertyGroupId
         ]
      ]
   ]
], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to fetch all option ids associated with the product and filtered by the group id. Once you have those you can build a payload to delete all `product_property` mappings. Since the mapping has two primary keys, you'll have to provide both the `optionId` and the `productId` to delete the mappings.

```php
$context = Context::createDefaultContext();
$criteria = new Criteria([$productId]);
$criteria->addAssociation('properties');
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('properties.groupId', $propertyGroupId));

/** @var ProductEntity|null $product */
$product = $container->get('product.repository')->search($criteria, $context)->first();

$payload = $product->getProperties()->map(function (PropertyGroupOptionEntity $option) use ($productId) {
    return ['optionId' => $option->getId(), 'productId' => $productId];
});

$container->get('product_property.repository')->delete($payload, $context);
```